# Helicity dependence in loop diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, helicity

I am trying to evaluate a diagram that looks like

[image: Feynman loop diagram]

The middle of the diagram is a fermion loop.  I know that the coupling between the $Z^0$ and fermions depends on the fermions' helicities, so it would be nice to evaluate the diagram separately for each fermion helicity.  When I try to evaluate the diagram, I clearly end up with an expression involving fermion propagators, and I don't see how those carry helicity information.

How can I deal with this?  To calculate the amplitude for each fermion helicity, can I just insert the usual projector $(1 \pm \gamma^5)/2$?